# Segment Length from an arrayList of Points --Java

Tags: java, point, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to calculate line segments (lengths) from an arrayList that I have created.
This is in JAVA. Everything works how I want it to, however I get this message: 
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    "

Having the "+1" for the index of the arraylist is causing trouble. This is what is causing the error message, however, it does calculate the line segments. It prints them then prints the dreaded error statement.

myPoints.get((i+1)).x ;  <--- (i+1) is causing the trouble
tempYFirst = myPoints.get(i).y;  <--- works fine without the +1, but it won't do what I want it to do.

```
public static void showStats(ArrayList<Point> myPoints)
{
    double distance = 0.0;
    double length;
    double tempX;
    double tempY;
    double tempX2;
    double tempY2;
    int tempFirst;
    int tempSecond;
    int tempYFirst;
    int tempYSecond;
    int xValue;
    int yValue;


    // Line segments are calculated by the distance formula of:
    // Sqrt ( (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y2)^2)
    for (int i = 0; i < myPoints.size(); i++) {

        tempFirst = myPoints.get(i).x;
        tempSecond = myPoints.get((i+1)).x ;
        tempYFirst = myPoints.get(i).y;
        tempYSecond = myPoints.get((i+1)).y;

        xValue = tempFirst - tempSecond;
        yValue = tempYFirst - tempYSecond;

        tempX2 = Math.pow(xValue, 2);
        tempY2 = Math.pow(yValue, 2);

        distance += Math.sqrt((tempX2 + tempY2));

        System.out.println(tempSecond);
     }// /
}
```

Comment: This isn't terribly surprising: what do you expect to happen when `i` points to the last point in the list?  (Do you want it to wrap around?  Do you want it to stop between the last two points in the list?)  Also, which `Point` class are you using?  At the very least, you could simplify this with `distance += Math.hypot(tempFirst - tempSecond, tempYFirst - tempYSecond)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to start the loop in 1. This way you don't have problems of index out of bounds...

```
for (int i = 1; i < myPoints.size(); i++) {

    tempFirst = myPoints.get(i-1).x;
    tempSecond = myPoints.get((i)).x ;
    tempYFirst = myPoints.get(i-1).y;
    tempYSecond = myPoints.get((i)).y;

    xValue = tempFirst - tempSecond;
    yValue = tempYFirst - tempYSecond;

    tempX2 = Math.pow(xValue, 2);
    tempY2 = Math.pow(yValue, 2);

    distance += Math.sqrt((tempX2 + tempY2));

    System.out.println(tempSecond);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to get the `Point` at index 2, but there are only 2 points, and in Java indexes only go from `0` to `size - 1`, or `1` in this case.  The problem is this line

```
tempSecond = myPoints.get((i+1)).x ;
```

When `i` is 1, `i + 1` is `2` and is out of bounds.  When on your last `Point`, better compare with the first `Point` to complete the loop:

```
tempSecond = myPoints.get((i+1) % myPoints.size()).x ;
```

This uses the `%` modulus operator to get the remainder when dividing by `myPoints.size()`, so that when `i + 1` gets too big, `0` is the result, i.e. the remainder when dividing `size` by `size` is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @rgettman's answer, try using the built-in `Point2D.distance` method, like so:

```
public static void showStats(ArrayList<Point> myPoints) {
    double distance = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < myPoints.size(); i++) {
        Point first = myPoints.get(i);
        Point second = myPoints.get((i+1) % myPoints.size());
        // use distance method
        distance += first.distance(second);
        System.out.println(second.x);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help as well. This will come in handy in the future, but I was able to make my code work perfectly!